# Why is my http requests with two words not working?

Tags: javascript, php, curl, axios

I am building a web app with leaflet and other API's for my software engineer course, but I am having a problem, every request I do to any API where I pass as parameters two words, separated by space or using the `encodeURI`, it returns me nothing, but when I do the same request with the same endpoint using the postman it returns me the JSON.

Scope

Request made by js to my PHP backend where runs a curl request.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

My js make a request using the country name to get the coordinates so I use the coordinates to move the map to the requested country, if the country name has 2 or more words it doesn't work, it also happens with the whether API, it receives the city name, if the city has 2 or more words I do not get any answer, but if I use the same two words on postman it works.

I already tried axios, ajax and fetch, and on backend I tried cURL and `file_get_contents()`.

If you want to check my code it is on my github https://github.com/vsrromero/victorRomero/tree/master/project1, but will place the request via cURL and AXIOS here:

```
//get list of countries
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loading-overlay').fadeOut('slow');

    axios.get('../assets/php/countriesRequest.php')
        .then(function (response) {
            countries = response.data.data;

            var selectElement = $('#countriesList select');

            // Make the first option selected as "select a country"
            var option = $('<option>').attr('value', '').text('Countries list');
            selectElement.append(option);

            // Renders the <select><option> elements with all countries
            countries.forEach(function (country) {
                var option = $('<option>').attr('value', country.countryName).text(country.countryName);
                selectElement.append(option);
            });

            // Get the country coordinates and set map view when the user selects a country
            selectElement.change(function () {
                var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
                axios.get('../assets/php/getCountryByName.php?countryName=' + selectedCountry)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.data.results[0]);
                        console.log(response.data.message);
                        var country = response.data.results[0].geometry;
                        coordinatesToTravel = [country.lat, country.lng];

                        console.log('Coordinates got from response: ', coordinatesToTravel);

                        // Set the map view to the selected country
                        map.setView(coordinatesToTravel, 5);
                        getCountryByLocation(coordinatesToTravel[0], coordinatesToTravel[1])

                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '/../../');
$dotenv->load();

$geonamesUser = $_ENV['GEONAMES_API_USER'];

function getAllCountries($geonamesUser) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    if(isset($_REQUEST['countryCode'])) {
        $url = 'http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=' . $geonamesUser . '&country=' . $_REQUEST['countryCode'];
    } else {
        $url='http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=' . $geonamesUser;
    }


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];
    
    usort($output['data'], function ($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['countryName'], $b['countryName']);
    });
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 
}

getAllCountries($geonamesUser);
?>
```

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '/../../');
$dotenv->load();

$opencage = $_ENV['OPENCAGE_API_KEY'];


    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=' . $_REQUEST['countryName'] . '&key=' . $opencage;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);

    $output = $decode;
    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['message'] = '$_REQUEST["countryName"] value got on php module: ' . $_REQUEST['countryName'];
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 
?>
```

As explained, I am having a problem, every request I do to any API where I pass as parameters two words, separated by space or using the encodeURI, I expect when I do a request with two words it returns me a JSON as happens when I use one word only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the space (and possibly other special characters).

In JS use `encodeURIComponent()`:

```
axios.get('../assets/php/getCountryByName.php?countryName=' + encodeURIComponent(selectedCountry))
```

In PHP use `urlencode()`:

```
$url='https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=' . urlencode($_REQUEST['countryName']) . '&key=' . urlencode($opencage);
```

Comment: I can't think of any other problem. Check the API documentation, maybe it requires you to handle spaces specially.

Comment: Sorry @Barmar I have answered but one thing I haven't tried is, use urlencode together with encodeURIComponent, because in my mind, using in just one side it would be enough, but it is noth, now when I use in both sides it works!

Comment: PHP decodes the parameter when it populates `$_REQUEST`, so you need to encode it again when calling out with `curl`.

Comment: Amazing Barmar, really good to know, I learn much more here than in chat gpt ;)